Does "put on to" mean the same thing as the phrasal verb "put onto" here?
In Aldous Huxley's book Brave New World, one of the characters discusses an attempt to implement a four-hour workday in Ireland, in the past.

"The whole of Ireland was put on to the four-hour day. What was the result? Unrest and a large increase in soma consumption; that was
all."

Is this the same as the phrasal verb "put onto" which means...
put onto (phrasal verb):
put someone onto someone or something
to alert someone to the existence of someone or something; to lead someone to someone or something.
Nancy put Elaine onto George, who knew of a job that Elaine might be interested in. Nancy put Elaine onto a good job lead.(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms")
...? If not, can you parse "put on to" for me? Thank you in advance :)

Not the same. To subject people or things to an arrangement, scheme or plan - Our company was short of money so we were put on [to] a three-day week to reduce costs (the factory and office were closed for two days out of five). My doctor said I was obese and put me on a diet. The 'to' is not always needed.

@Michael Harvey I've only heard it said in relation to a doctor prescribing medicine and diet to someone. Is this really a phrasal verb "put on" that you are talking about here?

As @Michael_Harvey says, this is not a case of the phrasal verb put onto. Instead, this is a tricky use of the preposition 'on to'. I can't find an OED sense that covers this exactly (though c.f on. prep. II.23: "Into, unto, to (some action, course, or condition).", on, adv., adj., n. 10.a: "Of a person: engaged in some function or course of action).
However, uses like this are relatively frequent with the preposition 'on:'

The doctors have her on the best treatment 
While her hip recover she's been placed on bed rest 
He's on indefinite leave, pending further investigation 
My boss put me on weekends [i.e. on the weekend shift] starting next month

These uses all express the notion of being made to engage in some activity, or scheduled in some way.  With the verb 'put', we sometimes use 'on to' instead of just 'on' (possibly by analogy with the phrasal verb 'put to'):

I was put on to three shifts immediately [1] 
[...] members of a control group may be put on to treatment [2]

I'd parse the excerpt from Brave New World as

The whole of Ireland was scheduled for a four-hour [work-]day. \

Or

The whole of Ireland was made to engage in a four-hour [work-]day

I.e.

Everybody in Ireland was made to work a four-hour day.


I don't see how "to" fits here. "put on" should be followed by a noun phrase, not a prepositional phrase. So either it should have been "put onto" or "to" is not needed.

@Barmar I'm writing 'on to' and 'onto' interchangeably (American English). Both are prepositions. I'm analyzing OP's sentence, structurally, as the verb "put", followed by the prepositional phrase "on to the four-hour day." I agree with your latter conclusion: 'to' is not needed. It could just as well have been "put on the four-hour day". It could also have read "The whole of Ireland was once forced on to the four-hour day." So "put on" is not acting as a phrasal verb in my analysis.

I'm British, and I can quite happily imagine I was put on [to] (or even onto!) a no-egg diet, a higher pay scale, the church cleaning rota, a different bronchodilator, a four-day week.

@George K. First, thank you for your exhaustive answer. What I still don't understand though, is whether "on to" is in this case also a preposition? AFAIK only "onto" is a preposition and the words "on" and "to" are are often next to one another and one of them (or maybe even both) is usually a part of a phrasal verb that appears in a sentence. I don't have access to the premium OED unfortunately. So I guess my questions is, is "on to" a preposition which means the same things as the preposition "on" which means: engaged in. "his attendant was out on errands"

Also onto and on remind  me of in and into. One of the could signify the accomplished stated of eg. already being "on a diet" the other of the period of transition from "no diet to on-diet). I don't know if my rationale is good enough though.

@StaticBounce There are guidelines for when to use 'on to' and when to use 'onto'. At the same time, there are many contexts in which two are interchangeable. In this case, in my analysis, 'on to' is a preposition. I should say that this is quite a tricky use, grammatically: the phrasal verb 'put on' is merging with the prepositional phrase "on [to] a four-hour day." Both help to create the meaning: the verb indicates enforcement, the prepositional phrase indicates the habitual/scheduled nature of the behavior they are engaging in.

I. Dictionary Meanings of "Put Onto" and "Put on To":
According to the Collins Dictionary, "put onto" can also be written as "put on to" in certain contexts:

put onto.
(preposition):
Refers to movement or placement on a surface.
Example:
"I took my bags inside, lowered myself onto the bed, and switched on the TV.".
.
Put on to (verb + preposition)

To connect by telephone.
To inform someone about a person or activity.
To direct someone to something beneficial.
Example: "I put the police on to him."


However, these meanings do not apply to the Brave New World context.
II. Other Examples of "put on to:".

Ludwig Guru.
"Put on to" can also mean being assigned or directed to something in informal contexts.
Example:
"I was put on to this project by my manager.".
.
BBC Example:..
"But National Grid has said it was obliged to link up wind farms in mid Wales so the energy they produce can be put on to the grid in Shropshire.”.
Here, "put on to" means transferred or added to the grid.
.
Guardian Example:.
“People will be put on to the streets in the middle of winter.”.

In this context, "put on to" implies forced or displaced onto the streets.
This sentence can be rewritten as:
"People will be forced onto the streets in the middle of winter."
III. Comparing "The Guardian" sentence with the original sentence:

Brave New World Sentence:.
“The whole of Ireland was put on to the four-hour day.”

In this context, "put on to" means subjected to or assigned to the four-hour workday policy, emphasizing enforcement rather than physical movement.
This sentence can be rewritten as:
"The whole of Ireland was subjected to the four-hour workday."
IV. Conclusion:
Both sentences involve enforcing a condition on people, but the contexts differ:

Guardian Sentence: Refers to physical displacement (being forced onto the streets).
Brave New World Sentence: Refers to policy enforcement (being subjected to a work schedule).

While the phrasing is similar, the difference depend on whether the action involves a physical move or a change in status or condition.
